# Setting global variables based on Node.js CLI arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I created a CLI in node.js. For each command the user passes in command line arguments such as environment and tenant. I want to set variables that can be accessed by any other file in the application.

I am using yargs so each one of my CLI commands takes in arguments and calls a function. Before calling the function I would like to set some global variables that the rest of the js files will use.

I realized I can use environment variables for this since you can set them in the code as well.

Comment: Have you tried any solutions yet? If you put them in  the answer it would help to solve the problem more quickly.

Comment: You could set environment variables but to me that doesn't really seem like their purpose. You could have a util function that parses the command line arguments and just import that and use it to parse the command line arguments where needed. You could also use a node session storage library, or persist the arguments to a database (but that's probably overkill).

Comment: @AdamSpecker My problem is with configuration... Every CLI command takes in two params Env and Subject. Using Env I need to be able to make sure a specific configuration file is used and using Tenant I need to be able to override the Tenant setting from that configuration file. Then any other file that loads in the configuration will have all of the settings from the appropriate configuration file with the correct Tenant. One of the main things here is that I cannot pass in environment variables, the environment and tenant come from the user.

Comment: It will be hard to answer this question without having some idea of the organization and code flow of your program. Do the config and tenant files need to change through the runtime of the program, or is it something that is captured on program start and remains constant?

Comment: @AdamSpecker I have a config/ folder with files in it such as .dev.js, .qa.js, .xyz.js. In this files I am doing module.exports on a JSON object with properties. I then have a configuration.js file that exports the appropriate config/ file that I am planning on requiring in all of my files. In index.js I have a function for each CLI command. Depending on what CLI command they call and what arguments they pass in I need to make sure I can call the correct config/.env.js file and override a value from the config/.env.js file so when I require configuration.js it will be the updated value.

Comment: @AdamSpecker My solution to this was to set environment variables in index.js, so then in configuration.js I can do a bunch of IF statements based on them and require the appropriate config/.env.js file and then do any overrides, then export. However, setting environment variables in the code isn't working for me for some reason because the environment variables are undefined for some reason.

Comment: Yeah setting environment variables like that feels like an anti pattern to me. I would suggest that you can resolve this just with function composition. I.E. have a util function that you import where you need, and have this function parse out the user provided command line arguments and return the appropriate configs. You obviously wouldn't want to do this if you needed to e.g. make network requests or do something expensive, but for your purposes I think it will do the trick. If you want to add your code to the original post, I will help you with a more formal solution.